# Can Windows 2008 "call home"?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access, remote-control, windows-server

I'd like to set up Windows 2008 r2 images that I can then access remotely.

Ideally, they'd "call home" once booted, and somehow provide a way for me to remotely administer them. They would likely have a dhcp-assigned internal IP in a different network from me, not visible from the internet, but port 80 should be open (although probably passing through web proxies).

Is this possible? Is there software that can do this, which I could then preinstall/preconfigure before distributing the image?

Comment: There's only a bazillion programs that can achieve this for you. LogMeIn, TeamViewer, etc., etc.

Comment: As far as I know, all these have to be somehow initiated at the other end...? Can TeamViewer work, if there's nobody logged in at the other end?

Comment: Neither of the two I mentioned require someone to be at the other end.